# how to merge next row into previous row in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to calculate value between start_time and end_time but I don't know how to right sql statement to do that.

This is my table.

[image]

Comment: Please include all data relevant to your question _directly in the question_, as _text_, not as images.  Then, also show us what the expected output should be, along with the logic behind that.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the table in textual form

Comment: Presumably you're ordering them by `usage_created`? And what version of MySQL?

Comment: Your question and description is not clear, please update if you want a difference between start time and end time or you to merge two rows?

Comment: @MangduYogii autually I want a different between start_time and end_time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 8 you can use the extremely useful [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) in particular `lead` to get a value from the next row.

```
select start_time, lead(end_time, 1) over() as end_time
from times
order by usage_created;

+---------------------+--------------------------+
| start_time          | end_time                 |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
| 2019-07-15 04:07:55 | 2019-07-15 04:08:23      |
| NULL                | NULL                     |
| 2019-07-15 04:08:31 | 2019-07-15 04:12:07      |
| NULL                | NULL                     |
| 2019-07-15 04:12:20 | 2019-07-15 04:12:28      |
| NULL                | NULL                     |
| 2019-07-15 04:11:14 | NULL                     |
+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

Then put that into a subquery to filter out the null rows.

```
select start_time, end_time
from (
    select start_time, lead(end_time, 1) over() as end_time
    from times
    order by usage_created
) t
where start_time is not null
  and end_time is not null;

+---------------------+---------------------+
| start_time          | end_time            |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2019-07-15 04:07:55 | 2019-07-15 04:08:23 |
| 2019-07-15 04:08:31 | 2019-07-15 04:12:07 |
| 2019-07-15 04:12:20 | 2019-07-15 04:12:28 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
    ; with cte as (
    select row_number() over (order by usage_created) AS sno, usage_created from tab )
    , ctstart as (
    select row_number() over (order by sno) as Slno, usage_created as Start_date from cte where slno%2=1)
    , ctend as (
    select row_number() over (order by sno) as Slno, usage_created as end_date from cte where slno%2=0)
    select ctstart.Slno,
    Datediff(second,  ctend.endate , ctstart.startdate) as diff     ---- here use your parameter in Datediff as per your need
    from ctstart inner join ctend on ctstart.Slno=ctend.Slno
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using window functions.  However, you need to include an `order by` *as part of the `lead()`* if you want the results to really work.  That is, there are no guarantees unless you have the `order by` there.

```
select start_time, end_time
from (select start_time, lead(end_time) over (order by usage_created) as end_time
      from times
     ) t
where start_time is not null and end_time is not null;
```

Note that this assumes that the rows are interleaved, as in your sample data.  You have a harder problem if this is not true.